# Howto: Use Custom Post Types as Submenu Items in Admin

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, admin-menu

In a plugin, i've created 3 Custom Post Types, for example:

- Dogs
- Cats
- Goldfish

I've also created a "Pets" Top-level menu page using `add_menu_page`wherein I'd like to add the 3 CPTs as **submenu items**.

**Problem:** I cant figure out how to add the Custom Post Types as Submenu Items.

The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) states:

> For Custom Post Types: add_submenu_page(
>   'edit.php?post_type=your_post_type', ... );

But I'm not getting it. Also, is this the best way to go about it?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. [This post](http://gregorcapuder.com/add-custom-post-type-sub-menu-custom-menu/) demonstrates what I need.